# True mean of randomly-generated numbers?

Tags: math, random, statistics, normal-distribution, gsl

I use GSL C++ library to generate random numbers now. The numbers obey a distribution, e.g. normal. So the expectation and std. deviation must be inputs, as well as the upper and lower bounds. It means if the generated number is not within the interval, then that number will be ignored.

The question is: someone said the input expectation and std. deviation are not true, because the pdf is truncated.

Are the inputs enough to represent the mean and std. deviation of random numbers? Is it a big difference between the inputs and true values? Is it anyway to analytically derive the true mean and std. deviation, with bounds?

Comment: This question is very little to do with programming and a lot to do with what you need the random numbers for. Of course the distribution will no longer be normal, the std. deviation will be smaller and (if the bounds are not symmetric) the mean will be different; whether that matters depends on the application

Comment: The mean and variance of a truncated distribution are computed in the same way as for any other distribution, namely as integrals of X and (X - mean(X))^2 with respect to the distribution over its support (region on which it is nonzero). Probably for a truncated normal, there are exact expressions for mean and variance in terms of mu, sigma, and the bounds. Further questions should be directed to stats.stackexchange.com, as this question, although interesting, is off topic here.